# Ajax добавление в бд

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста.У меня есть система сообщений так выбираешь диалог с помощью GET, вот у меня пишу отправку через ajax, но hash не передается GETOM.Вот сам ajax код.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".msg-post_input").click(function() {

var text = $("#post_new_txt").val();
var dataString = 'message='+ text;

if(text=='')
{
}
else
{
$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="background/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "messages/postmsg.php?id=<?=$myrow[id]?>",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("ol#update").prepend(html);
$("ol#update li:first").slideDown("slow");
document.getElementById('post_new_txt').value='';
document.getElementById('post_new_txt').focus();
$("#flash").hide();
}
});
} return false;
});
});
</script>
```

И вот как стараюсь добавить в бд.
     <?php

```
if (isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])) {
$hash = $_GET['hash'];

if (isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) {
$new_message = $_POST['message'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('','$hash','$myrow2[id]','$myrow[id]','$new_message',now(),'0')")or die(mysql_error());//заносим в базу сообщение
mysql_query("UPDATE message_group SET date_group=now() WHERE hash=$hash")or die(mysql_error());
          }}
          ?>
Помогите пожалуйста.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url: "messages/postmsg.php?id=<?=$myrow[id]?>",
```

ну вы же его сами в GET нигде не помещаете - с чего он там должен быть?
нада как то так

```
url: "messages/postmsg.php?hash=232323232323&id=<?=$myrow[id]?>",
```

Comment: @Ale_x Оо спасибо большое, а то мудохался долго.Спасибо большое еще раз.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).